# Updating a Dictionary within Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a code that is attempting to nest a dictionary within another dictionary. The code is shown below. The problem is that the dictionary "CC" rewrites writes itself every time through the loop. Is there a way to prevent this? I have tried appending to a list and then writing the dictionary with no luck. Nodes, CoordComboSort, and Xcoord are all other dictionaries within the code.

CoordComboSort looks something like this:

```
{0:[(1, 4, 5), (1, 7, 4)], .001:[(4, 6, 8), (3, 8, 6)]}
```

Nodes looks something like this:

```
{'time':[ 'A', 'B']}
```

I would like the final dictionary to look like this:

```
{'A': 0: [(1, 4, 5)], .001: [(4, 6, 8)], 'B': 0: [(1, 7, 4)], .001: [(3, 8, 6)]}   

CC = {}

for key in CoordComboSort.keys():
    for step in range(len(Xcoord[0])):
        CC[Nodes['time'][step]] = CoordComboSort[key][step]
```

The above code produces a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'A': [(4, 6, 8)], 'B': [(3, 8, 6)]}
```

Comment: You know that every key in a dict must be unique? It appears the key `Nodes['time'][step]` is producing the same key and therefore overwriting the last key:value

Comment: What is `Nodes`? `CoordComboSort`? `Xcoord`? What output are you expecting, and what do you get instead?

Comment: What do you mean by rewrite iteself? Try to provide input that can be ran by other SO members that will reproduce the behavior you're getting.

Comment: How does Xcoord look like?

Comment: **...and what do you get instead?** Why is your output a list containing a single three-tuple? You can't have two values for the key `.001`; you *could* have a two-element list of three-tuples for that key instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got your goal correctly but based on the examples you gave the following approach might work.

```
CC = {}

for step in range(len(Nodes['time'])):
    for key in CoordComboSort.keys():
        CC[Nodes['time'][step]] = {key : CoordComboSort[key][step] for key in CoordComboSort.keys()}
```

For your input, the output will be like this:

```
{'A': {0: (1, 4, 5), 0.001: (4, 6, 8)}, 'B': {0: (1, 7, 4), 0.001: (3, 8, 6)}}
```

Comment: This helped a ton! Sorry for not being super clear in the question. Thanks!